# How to safely compare two unsigned integer counters?

Tags: c++, c, integer-overflow, unsigned-integer

We have two unsigned counters, and we need to compare them to check for some error conditions:

```
uint32_t a, b;
// a increased in some conditions
// b increased in some conditions
if (a/2 > b) {
   perror("Error happened!");
   return -1;
}
```

The problem is that `a` and `b` will overflow some day. If `a` overflowed, it's still OK. But if `b` overflowed, it would be a false alarm. How to make this check bulletproof?

I know making `a` and `b` `uint64_t` would delay this false-alarm. but it still could not completely fix this issue.

===============

Let me clarify a little bit: the counters are used to tracking memory allocations, and this problem is found in [dmalloc/chunk.c](https://github.com/siana/dmalloc/blob/master/chunk.c):

```
#if LOG_PNT_SEEN_COUNT
  /*
   * We divide by 2 here because realloc which returns the same
   * pointer will seen_c += 2.  However, it will never be more than
   * twice the iteration value.  We divide by two to not overflow
   * iter_c * 2.
   */
  if (slot_p->sa_seen_c / 2 > _dmalloc_iter_c) {
    dmalloc_errno = ERROR_SLOT_CORRUPT;
    return 0;
  }
#endif
```

Comment: What are these counters for, and why are you comparing them?

Comment: It is not clear what you really want to do here. There might be many solutions depending on the requirement. For example reset both counters when one is overflowing.

Comment: If you use a `64` bit number and increase it 2 billion times per second it will take 120 years to overflow.

Comment: This problem is found in dmalloc/chunk.c, line 1875, `slot_p->sa_seen_c / 2 > _dmalloc_iter_c`.

Comment: What is the lifetime of this program ? Using 64-bit counters, and incrementing once per nanosecond, the counters will not overflow for over 584 years.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you misinterpreted the comment in the code:

> We divide by two to not overflow `iter_c * 2`.

No matter where the values are coming from, it is safe to write `a/2` but it is not safe to write `a*2`. Whatever unsigned type you are using, you can always divide a number by two while multiplying may result in overflow.

If the condition would be written like this:

```
if (slot_p->sa_seen_c > _dmalloc_iter_c * 2) {
```

then roughly half of the input would cause a wrong condition. That being said, if you worry about counters overflowing, you could wrap them in a class:

```
class check {
    unsigned a = 0;
    unsigned b = 0;
    bool odd = true;
    void normalize() {
        auto m = std::min(a,b);
        a -= m;
        b -= m;
    }
public:
    void incr_a(){ 
        if (odd) ++a;
        odd = !odd;
        normalize();
    }
    void incr_b(){ 
        ++b;
        normalize();
    }
    bool check() const { return a > b;}
}
```

Note that to avoid the overflow completely you have to take additional measures, but if `a` and `b` are increased more or less the same amount this might be fine already.

Answer (score 4):

Note overflows as they occur.

```
uint32_t a, b;
bool aof = false;
bool bof = false;

if (condition_to_increase_a()) {
  a++;
  aof = a == 0;
}

if (condition_to_increase_b()) {
  b++;
  bof = b == 0;
}

if (!bof && a/2 + aof*0x80000000 > b) {
   perror("Error happened!");
   return -1;
}
```

Each `a, b` interdependently have 2<sup>32</sup> + 1 different states reflecting value and conditional increment.  Somehow, more than an `uint32_t` of information is needed.  Could use `uint64_t`, variant code paths or an auxiliary variable like the `bool` here.

Answer (score 4):

The posted code actually doesn’t seem to use counters that may wrap around.

What the comment in the code is saying is that it is safer to compare `a/2 > b` instead of `a > 2*b` because the latter could potentially overflow while the former cannot.  This particularly true of the type of `a` is larger than the type of `b`.

Answer (score 2):

Normalize the values as soon as they wrap by forcing them both to wrap at the same time.  Maintain the difference between the two when they wrap.

Try something like this;

```
uint32_t a, b;
// a increased in some conditions
// b increased in some conditions
if (a or b is at the maximum value) {
   if (a > b)
   {
     a = a-b; b = 0;
   }
   else
   {
     b = b-a; a = 0;
   }
}
if (a/2 > b) {
   perror("Error happened!");
   return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If even using 64 bits is not enough, then you need to code your own "var increase" method, instead of overload the `++` operator (which may mess your code if you are not careful).

The method would just reset var to '0' or other some meaningfull value.

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to ensure that action `x` happens no more than twice as often as action `y`, I would suggest doing something like:

```
uint32_t x_count = 0;
uint32_t scaled_y_count = 0;

void action_x(void)
{
  if ((uint32_t)(scaled_y_count - x_count) > 0xFFFF0000u)
    fault();
  x_count++;
}

void action_y(void)
{
  if ((uint32_t)(scaled_y_count - x_count) < 0xFFFF0000u)
    scaled_y_count+=2;
}
```

In many cases, it may be desirable to reduce the constants in the comparison used when incrementing `scaled_y_count` so as to limit how many `action_y` operations can be "stored up".  The above, however, should work precisely in cases where the operations remain anywhere close to balanced in a 2:1 ratio, even if the number of operations exceeds the range of `uint32_t`.